# Why won't my while loop terminate?

Tags: java, while-loop

I've noticed when using while loops in my java programs that when using a boolean type to terminate it does not seem to be working.  I typed up something simple to test it.  The code completes through i = 9 and then test is printed out as false.

```
    public class LoopTesting {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean test = true;

        while(test) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                if(i == 5) test = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(test);
    } 
}
```

EDIT: In response to afzalex's answer I tested this code:

```
while(test) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);

        }

        test = false;

        for(int i = 11; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

and it prints to 19.

Comment: Its actually working properly , printed 1..9 and the "test" , exactly what is expected

Comment: The while loop terminates, that is why it prints `false`.

Comment: @alfasin thats a single threaded (main thread) example, you don't have synchronisation or concurrency issues and optimizations to care about.

Comment: The while loop will only check the condition at the beginning of the loop. The beginning of the next while iteration does not start before the end of the first. So it is no wonder it prints up to 20, as this is still done in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to happen when one of your inner for-loops satisfies a condition. Can you tell us what you're trying to do?

Comment: @TheMetalBeard - I am just experimenting and learning the language right now.  I am now guessing the entire loop will be executed at least once no matter where the boolean is changed and will not be rechecked until the next loop.  Is that correct?

Comment: @eckes - Thank you.  That clears up my confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You changed `test` value inside for loop. but condition for `for` loop is `i < 10`, not `test`.
So `for` loop go on iterating until it ends.
Then while is terminated as you had set `test` as `false` when control was inside `for` loop.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want

```
    while(test) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            if(i == 5) {
             test = false;
             break;
            }
        }
    }
```

or more simply

```
int i = -1;

while(test) {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
        if(i == 5) {
           test = false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your `while` loop not closing is because you have an embedded `for` loop in your code. What happens, is your code will enter the `while` loop, because `while(test)` will result in `true`. Then, your code will enter the `for` loop. Inside of your for loop, you have the code looping from 1-10. This loop is based off of the `Integer` value `i`. The inside loop is basically saying `while(i < 10)`, so this inside loop is not effected by the `boolean` value of test.

```
 while(test) { // This loop will continue to run until test == false
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) { // This loop will continue to run until i > 9
              test = false; // This will execute on the first loop of the inner loop, but it is not checked at the outer loop until the inner loop is complete
        }
    }
```

Hope that makes sense. Your issue is that the boolean is corresponding to the outer loop, nothing is stopping the inner loop from running.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your logic. The `test` variable isn't getting checked until your inner for-loop completes. If you only want to iterate 5 times, you can do this:

```
while(test) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if(i == 5){ 
            test = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But you probably want to do something like this:

```
...
int i = 1;
while(test) {
    if(i == 5)
        test = false
    else i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you second question code looks like if you replace while and for with a simple if/goto. Maybe this is easier to understand for you:

```
loopA: // while
if (test) {
  int i1 = 1;
  loopB: // for 1
  if (i1 < 10) {
    System.out.println(i1);
    i1++;
    goto loopB;
  }

  test = false;

  int i2= 11;
  loopC: // for 2
  if (i2 < 20) {
    System.out.println(i2);
    i2++;
    goto loopC;
  }
  goto loopA;
}
System.out.println(test);
```